# Expanding View Contact Dashboard or Showing Contact Record to Non-Admin User

Tags: civimember, contacts, contact-view

I was curious to know if anyone had expanded on the Contact Dashboard or found a way to show the contact record to a non-admin user. The Contact Dashboard doesn't give all the details that some people (like check numbers or transactions IDs) want, so I was thinking about exposing the contact record. Can this be done at all?

Thanks! Matthew

**EDIT 2017 JANUARY 22 -------------------**
Included are the images most relevant to this discussion. The first image is the user profile, and as you can see, with my profile (the administrator's profile that is) you can see two links at the bottom: "View contact record" and "View Contact Dashboard". "View Contact Dashboard" is already visible to my site's members, but not "View contact record", which holds a greater trove of information for members.

The second image is what I show when "View contact record" is clicked. The URL it can be found at:

```
/civicrm/contact/view?reset=1&cid=2
```

[image: User Profile]
[image: Contact Record]

Comment: Just to make sure everyone know what you are referring to, can you post a relative url to the Civi page you are talking about, or attach a screenshot?

Comment: @Jackrabbithanna I have added the information and images as per your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Drupal?  If so go to the permissions page a /admin/people/permissions and check the "CiviCRM: view my contact " permission either for authenticated users or whatever user role you want to be able to see their own contact.  Try that and see if it works....its possible thought that you may need to enable "CiviCRM: access CiviCRM" for that user role too, and you may not want to allow users to access anything other than contact page, after trying these things, we can more better think of solutions that could help you